# Can some tell me why I am seg faulting in this simple C program?

Tags: c, malloc, segmentation-fault

I keep on getting seg faulted after I end my first for loop, and for the life of me I don't why. 
The file I'm scanning is just 18 strings in 18 lines. 
I thinks the problem is the way I'm mallocing the double pointer called picks, but I don't know exactly why.
I'm am only trying to scanf strings that are less than 15 chars long, so I don't see the problem. Can someone please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LENGTH 100

int main( int argc,char *argv[] )
{

   char* string = malloc( 15*sizeof(char) );
   char** picks = malloc(15*sizeof(char*));
   FILE* pick_file = fopen( argv[l], "r" );
   int num_picks;


   for( num_picks=0 ; fgets( string, MAX_LENGTH, pick_file ) != NULL ; num_picks++ )
     {
       scanf( "%s", picks+num_picks );
     }
   //this is where i seg fault
   int x;
   for(x=0; x<num_picks;x++)
     printf("s\n", picks+x);
}
```

Comment: A segmentation fault always occurs when you access memory that you don't have permission to access. In most cases that means you're accessing an array beyond its bounds [or an object that has not been allocated/ variable not defined]. Keep that in mind the next time you get one - it kindof eliminates the search, especially with such a simple program as this.

Answer (score 9):

`picks` is a pointer-to-a-pointer: that means that the things it points to, are themselves pointers.

When you do this:

```
char** picks = malloc(15*sizeof(char*));
```

You are making `picks` point to a block of 15 pointers - which is fine as far as it goes (although, since you want to read in *18* lines, you really need 18 here instead of 15).  This means that `picks` points to a block of variables in memory like this:

```
| picks (char **) | --------> | picks[0] (char *)  | ----> ?
                              | picks[1] (char *)  | ----> ?
                              | picks[2] (char *)  | ----> ?
                              | ...                |
                              | picks[14] (char *) | ----> ?
```

As you can see, those 15 `char *` pointers are now unintialised - they don't point to anything.  You can't start using them until you allocate some memory for those, too - you need to do something like this:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    picks[i] = malloc(15);
}
```

*Now*, after that, the memory layout looks like this:

```
| picks (char **) | --------> | picks[0] (char *)  | ----> | picks[0][0] (char)  |
                                                           | picks[0][1] (char)  |
                                                           | ...                 |
                                                           | picks[0][14] (char) |

                              | picks[1] (char *)  | ----> | picks[1][0] (char)  |
                                                           | ...                 |

                              | ...                |
```

...and you now have places to store all those characters you want to read.

Comment: I am moved by the poetic beauty of the ascii representation, almost to the point of weeping .. for joy that this may be the last incarnation of this question :)

Comment: Agreed... I was to answer something but I am humbled by what the "Load new Answers" Orange bar brought before my eyes !!

Answer (score 5):

1. `string` is only getting allocated enough memory to store one character (`sizeof(char)`).  If you want to store more characters, you'll need to multiply `sizeof(char)` by the size of the string you want to store, plus one for the null at the end.
2. Instead of:

   ```
   char** picks = malloc(15*sizeof(char));
   ```

   You want to do this:

   ```
   char** picks = malloc(15*sizeof(char*));
   ```

   Each element of the `picks` array needs to be big enough to hold a pointer.

Comment: ... and the elements of picks need to ba allocated as well.

Comment: ...and there needs to be at least 18 of them, not 15.

Comment: For (1), note that a one-character string is enough to store the zero-byte terminator, and hence that's long enough for an empty string and nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, in C strings are stored as byte (char) arrays, and have to be allocated. In this situation, the string used to read he file should be allocated for MAX_LENGTH+1 (+1 for the string terminator, \0) chars:

```
char* string = malloc( (MAX_LENGTH+1) * sizeof(char) );
```

This will allocate enough memory for a string of maximum length: MAX_LENGTH.

Another problem is that the array of pointers `char **picks` is not allocated to store the 18 strings you're expecting to read:

It has to be allocated for 15 char pointers (char *), which also have to be allocated in the first loop.

```
int main( int argc,char *argv[] )
{
   ...
   char* string = malloc( (MAX_LENGTH+1) * sizeof(char) );
   char** picks = malloc(15*sizeof(char *));
   FILE* pick_file = fopen( argv[l], "r" );
   int num_picks;

   for( num_picks=0 ; fgets( string, MAX_LENGTH, pick_file ) != NULL ; num_picks++ )
     {
       printf("pick a/an %s ", string );
       //--- allocate the char array to store the current string
       picks[num_picks] = malloc (15 * sizeof(char));
       sscanf(string, "%s", picks[num_picks] );
     }

   for(int x=0; x<num_picks;x++)
     printf("%s\n", picks[x]);
}
```

You also have to test malloc() return value, and you may want to test if the file content really is as expected and does not contain more lines, or lines longer than 15 chars.

---

Also scanf() reads the standard input, I replaced it with sscanf(), and added the missing '%' sign in the second printf().

Answer (score 1):

- The location pointed to by `string` is only allocated space for *one* char, but you try to read up to `MAX_LENGTH` chars into it;
- The location pointed to by `picks` is only allocated space for 15 `char *` pointers, but you apparently want to store pointers to 18 strings there;
- The location pointed to by `picks` is allocated but never initialised.  You need to make those 15 (or 18) pointers actually point to something themselves, before you hand them to `scanf`.

In this case, there is actually no need for dynamic allocation at all - you could do what you want with arrays:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 100
#define MAX_LINES 18

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char string[MAX_LENGTH];
    char picks[MAX_LINES][MAX_LENGTH];
    FILE *pick_file = NULL;
    int num_picks;

    if (argc > 1)
        pick_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (pick_file == NULL)
        return 1;

    for (num_picks = 0; num_picks < MAX_LINES && fgets(string, MAX_LENGTH, pick_file) != NULL; num_picks++)
    {
        printf("pick a/an %s ", string);
        scanf("%s", picks[num_picks]);
    }

    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < num_picks; x++)
        printf("%s\n", picks[x]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it because in the line:
`for( num_picks=0 ; fgets( string, MAX_LENGTH, pick_file ) != NULL ; num_picks++ )`
`MAX_LENGTH` is 100 but you're reading into the variable `string`, which can only hold an individual character?

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating an array of fifteen `char*` for `picks`:

```
char** picks = malloc(15*sizeof(char*));
```

Now `picks` has enough space to store fifteen `char*`, but you never actually put any pointers inside that would point to memory that should contain the read characters.

You need to allocate memory for these strings that will be read with `scanf`. At the moment `scanf` just writes the data to wherever the pointers in `picks` (that have not been initialized to point anywhere useful) are pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

u r getting seg fault here.

`scanf( "%s", picks+num_picks );`

instead do this,

```
for( num_picks=0 ; fgets( string, MAX_LENGTH, pick_file ) != NULL ; num_picks++ )
 {
   pics[num_picks] = (char* )malloc(100);
   scanf( "%s", picks+num_picks );
 }
```

The problem is, u allocated `**pics` to hold 15 strings, but u read the strings without allocating the space for those strings. make sure u always read into allocated pointers.